# How can I show a the Cartan subalgebra being abelian implies its adjoint representation on the original Lie algebra completely commutes?

Tags: lie-algebras, associativity, semisimple-lie-algebras

I am reading a set of notes on the classification of simple Lie algebras, in which the claim is made that since $\mathfrak h\subset g$, a Cartan subalgebra is abelian it then follows that the adjoint action of $\mathfrak h$ on $\mathfrak g$ completely commutes. My attempt at showing this is the following:

$$(\text{ad}(h_1)\circ \text{ad}(h_2))(g)=[h_1,[h_2,g]]=[[h_1,h_2],g]=[[h_2,h_1],g]=[h_2,[h_1,g]]=(\text{ad}(h_2)\circ \text{ad}(h_1))(g).$$ However, the second equality relies on the fact that the algebra is associative, which isn't necessarily true for a Lie algebra. I'm also concerned that since $[h_1,h_2]=0$ this doesn't make sense. Is there a simple way to see this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you point out yourself, the Lie bracket is in general not associative. Instead one has the [Jacobi identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity) which tells us that

$$[h_1, [h_2, g]] + [h_2, [g, h_1]] + [g, [h_1, h_2]]].$$

Now, that $h_1, h_2$ commute means by definition that $[h_1, h_2]=0$, hence the last term is $=0$, hence

$$[h_1, [h_2, g]] = - [h_2, [g, h_1]].$$

Now use anticommutativity and bilinearity of the Lie bracket to write this as

$$= -[h_2, -[h_1, g]] = [h_2, [h_1,g]].$$

---

Or, since you write "adjoint action", maybe you know already (as follows from the Jacobi identity) that the adjoint action defines a Lie algebra representation, i.e.

$$ad([x,y]) =ad(x) \circ ad(y) -ad(y) \circ ad(x) \qquad \text{for all } x,y \in g,$$

and now you apply this to $h_1, h_2$ with $[h_1, h_2] = 0$.In short, if two Lie algebra elements commute, their adjoints commute.

Comment: Yes, the Jacobi identity is sort of a Lie algebra ghost of the Lie group action by Adjoint on its Lie algebra. At that level, the more usual arguments about commuting _groups_ giving commuting _operators works as expected. "Taking a derivative" gives the Lie algebra version (noting the Jacobi identity, which _follows_ if/when the action come from a Lie group action, but then can be separately axiomatized without mentioning Lie groups).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a root system: write ${\cal g}={\cal h}\oplus_{\alpha\in A}g_a$ where $A$ is a root system, if $x\in {\cal g}_a, u,u'\in {\cal h}, [u,[u',x]]=a(u)a(u')x$, if $x\in {\cal h}, [u,[u',x]]=0$.